# Rails: Dragonfly UID not found although it displays the path correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dragonfly-gem

I have a Filemanager app, which doesn't use a Model and doesn't store anything in the database. Thus, I had to do the setup a bit differently. My setup is as follows:

**When generating the files**

```
files.each do |file|
    filesObj = {
        "name" => file,
        "path" => File.expand_path(directory_name + '/' + file),
        "modified" => File.ctime(directory_name + '/' + file),
        "size" => (File.size(directory_name + '/' + file).to_f / 2**20),
        "url" => url + file,
        "thumb_url" => 'http://' + request.host_with_port() + '/' + dragonfly.app.fetch(url_path + '/' + file).thumb('400x200').url
      }
end
```

The urls are generated properly, one such url is: `http://localhost:3000/media/W1siZiIsIi9tZWRpYS8xLkpQRyJdLFsicCIsInRodW1iIiwiNDAweDIwMCJdXQ?sha=051428e06f681fb2`

When I go to that URL, I get the following in the terminal:
`Started GET "/media/W1siZiIsIi9tZWRpYS8xLkpQRyJdLFsicCIsInRodW1iIiwiNDAweDIwMCJdXQ?sha=051428e06f681fb2" for ::1 at 2017-03-01 12:57:58 -0500
DRAGONFLY: uid /media/1.JPG not found
DRAGONFLY: GET /media/W1siZiIsIi9tZWRpYS8xLkpQRyJdLFsicCIsInRodW1iIiwiNDAweDIwMCJdXQ?sha=051428e06f681fb2 404`

The file exists in the media folder. Any idea why it's failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It failed for a couple of reasons

1. I didn't have `ImageMagick` installed.
2. The `gem` is outdated, it looks for `convert` command, which the `ImageMagick` dropped from version `7.0`.